# Replace values in Json using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a json file in which i would like to change values and save again as a Json:
Values that need to be updated:

1. domain
2. repo

   ```
   [
    {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/LS_New')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedServices",
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "properties": {
            "description": "Connection",
            "annotations": [],
            "type": "AzureDatabricks",
            "typeProperties": {
              "domain": "https://url.net",
              "accessToken": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                  "referenceName": "LS_vault",
                  "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "TOKEN"
              },
              "newClusterNodeType": "Standard_DS4_v2",
              "newClusterNumOfWorker": "2:10",
              "newClusterSparkEnvVars": {
                "PYSPARK_PYTHON": "/databricks/python3/bin/python3"
              },
              "newClusterVersion": "7.2.x-scala2.12"
            }
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/LS_evaKeyVault')]"
          ]
        },
    {
          "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/PIP_Log')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
          "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
          "properties": {
            "description": "Unzip",
            "activities": [
              {
                "name": "Parse",
                "description": "This notebook",
                "type": "DatabricksNotebook",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                  "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                  "retry": 0,
                  "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                  "secureOutput": false,
                  "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                  "notebookPath": "/dataPipelines/main_notebook.py",
                  "baseParameters": {
                    "businessgroup": {
                      "value": "@pipeline().parameters.businessgroup",
                      "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "project": {
                      "value": "@pipeline().parameters.project",
                      "type": "Expression"
                    }
                  },
                  "libraries": [
                    {
                      "pypi": {
                        "package": "cytoolz"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "pypi": {
                        "package": "log",
                        "repo": "https://b73gxyht"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "linkedServiceName": {
                  "referenceName": "LS_o",
                  "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                }
              }
            ],
            "parameters": {
              "businessgroup": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "test"
              },
              "project": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "log-analytics"
              }
            },
            "annotations": []
          },
          "dependsOn": [
            "[concat(variables('factoryId'), '/linkedServices/LS_o')]"
          ]
        }
    ]
   ```

I tried using regex but i am only able to update 1 value :

```
<valuesToReplace>
  <valueToReplace>
    <regExSearch>(\/PIP_Log[\w\W]*?[pP]roperties[\w\W]*?[lL]ibraries[\w\W]*?[pP]ypi[\w\W]*?"repo":\s)"(.*?[^\\])"</regExSearch>
    <replaceWith>__PATValue__</replaceWith>
  </valueToReplace>

  <valueToReplace>
    <regExSearch>('\/LS_New[\w\W]*?[pP]roperties[\w\W]*?[tT]ypeProperties[\w\W]*?"domain":\s"(.*?[^\\])")</regExSearch>
    <replaceWith>__LSDomainName__</replaceWith>
  </valueToReplace>
</valuesToReplace>
```

Here is the powershell code. The loop  goes  through all the values that are to be replaced.
I tried using dynamic variable  in select-string and looping, but it doesn't seem to work

```
foreach($valueToReplace in $configFile.valuesToReplace.valueToReplace)
        {
          
            $regEx = $valueToReplace.regExSearch
            $replaceValue = '"' + $valueToReplace.replaceWith + '"'
          
            $matches = [regex]::Matches($json, $regEx)
            
            $matchExactValueRegex = $matches.Value | Select-String -Pattern """repo\D:\s*(.*)" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
            $updateReplaceValue = $matches.Value | Select-String -Pattern "repo\D:\s\D__(.*)__""" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
            $updateReplaceValue = """$patValue"""
    
    $json1 = [regex]::Replace($json, $matchExactValueRegex , $updateReplaceValue)
    
    $matchExactValueRegex1 = $matches.Value | Select-String -Pattern """domain\D:\s*(.*)" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
            $updateReplaceValue1 = $matches.Value | Select-String -Pattern "domain\D:\s\D__(.*)__""" | % {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
            $updateReplaceValue1 = """$domainURL"""
     
          
            $json = [regex]::Replace($json1, $matchExactValueRegex1 , $updateReplaceValue1)
          }
          else
          {
            Write-Warning "Inactive config value"
          }
        
        
        $json | Out-File $armFileWithReplacedValues
```

Where am i missing??

Comment: JSON is a data structure. You don't use a regex, since `Convertfrom-JSON` creates a nice PS object.

Answer (score 1):

You should not peek and poke in serialized files (as e.g. Json files) directly. Instead deserialize the file with the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-7) cmdlet, make your changes to the object and serialize it again with the [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7) cmdlet:

```
$Data = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
$Data[0].properties.typeproperties.domain = '_LSDomainName__'
$Data[1].properties.activities.typeproperties.libraries[1].pypi.repo = '__PATValue__'
$Data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 | Out-File $armFileWithReplacedValues
```